# Excel question for IF formula with 3 boxes

Tags: excel

I am trying to figure out how to look at data from 3 boxes and generate one answer in one cell.
[image: image for explanation]

I want excel to look at the date entered into g, h, or i and return the type based on what code was entered. Only one code will be in any of the three boxes at a time.

Comment: `=CONCAT(G1,H1,I1)` should do the trick. No reason to make it complicated.

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(G2&H2&I2,K:L,2,FALSE)`

Comment: Both of the above will work but I question why you wouldn't have only one column named AbsenceCode and then populate it with P, V, or S.  Use your dropdown box to only populate valid data.  Having 3 different columns is not good form and you may have issues if you wish to add functionality.